# Detecting if a templated type is itself a templated type

Tags: c++, templates, boost, types

I am writing a method which is in charge of formatting and printing information.

There is a problem/feature in `boost::optional<T>`, which [will print an extra blank space](https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2009/02/148938.php) when outputting it to a stream if and only if the `optional` has a value.

I can see two options:

- Using two different functions: A general one and one which explicitly deals with `boost::optional<T>`
- Using a single function which can detect if the argument is of type `boost::optional<T>` and deal with it accordingly

**Option 1** could be something like this:

```
template <typename T>
void print(const T& o)
{
    std::cout << o << "\n";
}

template <typename T>
void print_optional(const boost::optional<T>& o)
{
    if (o)
        print(*o);
    else 
        print("--");
}
```

It works, but it has the problem that no compilation error happens if we call `print()` with a `boost::optional`. I know of `static_assert` and `std::is_type`, **but since `boost::optional` is itself templated I don't know how to check against it.**

**Option 2** would be ideal for me, but the issue remains: **how to ask the code whether a variable is a `boost::optional<T>` regardless of T?**

Comment: The question as posed: "you cannot". A type is a type. However, you don't want that, you want to overload (partial) specializations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other answers said, template overload should have solved your problem; just to answer your question directly, you can check whether the type is an instantiation of `boost::optional` via a class template with partial specialization, e.g.

```
template <typename>
struct is_optional : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_optional<boost::optional<T>> : std::true_type {};

template <typename T>
void print(const T& o)
{
    static_assert(!is_optional<T>::value, "Please use print_optional instead.");
    std::cout << o << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You could just overload the `print` function:

```
template <typename T>
void print(const T& o)
{
    std::cout << o << "\n";
}

template <typename T>
void print(const boost::optional<T>& o)
{
    if (o)
        print(*o);
    else 
        print("--");
}
```

This will correctly choose the second overload if you pass a `boost::optional`, and the first overload otherwise.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/104cb8d4203ad4be)

Comment: Actually, boost variant does this out of the box (but adds a space): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbaa09f05dabfa90

Answer (score 2):

Just overload `print`:

```
template <typename T>
void print(const T& o)
{
    std::cout << o << "\n";
}

template <typename T>
void print(const boost::optional<T>& o)
{
    if (o)
        print(*o);
    else 
        print("--");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding a solution not presented by any of the former answers:

You can use a struct with template specialization to check if the type is `optional` like this:

```
template < typename >
struct is_optional : std::false_type {};

template < typename T >
struct is_optional<std::optional<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

Now, you can use `std::enable_if_t` to have a single method that behaves differently for `optional<T>` inputs and other inputs:

```
template < typename T >
std::enable_if_t<!is_optional<T>::value, void> print(const T& o)
{
    std::cout << o << "\n";
}

template < typename T >
std::enable_if_t<is_optional<T>::value, void> print(const T& o)
{
    if (o)
        print(*o);
    else 
        print("--");
}
```

**Note:** Overloading the method explicitly for `optional<T>` is a better solution, since it is cleaner, more readable and doesn't require the `is_optional` struct, but this is nonetheless a valid implementation.